# docker centos:6.6 image "/bin/sh: java: command not found" java is installed

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, docker

I have a docker container from [centos](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/centos/) where I installed maven and jdk1.7 for jenkins slaves (to cut down on the build time where jenkins installs jdk and maven)

When I start a container

> docker run -t -i jenkv1 /bin/bash
>
> [root@095586d24ad9 /]# java -version
>
> java version "1.7.0_51"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

I see java but if it gets started this way:

> docker run -t -i jenkv1 /bin/sh java
>
> "/bin/sh: java: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `docker run -t -i jenkv1 java  -version` (which will not do much)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: I installed java under /opt and though just adding the java env to /etc/defaults/java it would work but the $PATH is not correct when I run: docker run -t -i jenkv1 echo $PATH